# Malware propgating through usb debugging

Tags: security, usb, usb-debugging, malware, virus

Summary:

Computer probably had malware. Didn't know. Connected phone to use as midi. Could have turned on usb debugging or usb tethering to see if that helped without knowing what it does as I was an idiot at the time. 4 months or so has passed. No evidence of malware. Should I bother with formatting it?

Questions:

1. Should I bother with formatting it?
2. Is it even possible for malware to exist without any indicators?

Extra info:

Did antivirus scans with Avast, Malwarebytes, Kaspersky and Google Play Protect. None of them found anything.

Comment: How old is your device? The older the device the higher the chance for malware to hide. Some malware even can root your device in background which can make it very hard to detect: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/new-abstractemu-malware-roots-android-devices-evades-detection/

Comment: @Robert pretty recent. It still gets security updates and stuff. And android version is pretty recent as well.

Comment: Then installed malware should not have much options to harm you. A potential attack would be to display popup windows at the right time asking for credentials (phishing attack). or to misuse the dive for ad fraud (downloading ads in the background and simulate clicks on it).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Robert what about the possibility of spyware?

Comment: Apps on Android are restricted, and can not spy much on you without explicit permission by you. The default sensors are accessible but for e.g. location the app needs to be granted permission by you (system dialog). The higher the Android version the less an app can spy.

Comment: @Robert Wouldn't malware be able to bypass this? As i said, i had usb debugging enabled.

Comment: Yes indeed I forgot that way. But you should be able to reset those changes by executing `adb shell pm reset-permissions`.